# Por que no se guarda mi comentario en la base de datos y por que no me lo muestra en cada post, Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

No se me esta guardando cada comentario y tampoco me los muestra aunque los haga desde el admin de Django, necesito mostrar el comentario y el usuario que ralizo tal comentario no me da error me da un codigo "POST /posts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2885 pero cuando quiero ver el comentario que realize no me lo muestra y tampoco se guarda en la base de datos, pero cuando lo hago desde el admin de Django se guarda pero no me muestra el comentario en la vista

**Este es mi codigo**

**views.py**

```
def create_comment(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        comment = Comment(
            content=request.POST["comment"],
            author_id=request.user.pk
        )
        #comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(content)
        comment.save()


        return redirect("/posts")
    
    return render(request, 'posts/comment.html', {'post': post})
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author.username, self.content}'
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.posts, name='posts_list'),
    path('create', views.create_post, name='post_create'),
    path('<int:id>', views.post, name='post_detail'),
    path('comment/<int:id>', views.create_comment, name='post_comment'),
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit_post, name='post_edit'),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete_post, name='post_delete')
]
```

**comments.html el html donde se crean los comentarios**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/posts/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}   
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="Comenta"></textarea>
        <button>comentar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**posts.html (el html donde se muestran todas publicaciones)**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .posts{
            margin: 0px 50px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            gap: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <a href="create">crear publicacion</a>
    <section class="posts">
        {% for post in posts %}
            
                <article class="card" >
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="{{ post.get_url }}">
                            <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                        </a>    
                        <p>{{ comment.author }}</p>:<p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
                        <p>{{ post.created_date }}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
                        <a href="/posts/edit/{{ post.id }}"><button>Editar</button></a>
                        <a class="delete_confirmation" onclick="deleteConfirmation({{ post.id }})" href="/posts/delete/{{ post.id }}"><button>borrar</button></a>
                        <a href="/posts/comment/{{ post.id }}"><button>comentar</button></a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="/posts/{{ post.id }}">
                        <img class="card-img-bottom" src="{{ post.img }}">
                    </a>
                </article>
        {% endfor %}
    </section>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/posts.js' %}"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

** esto es lo que me muestra la consola a la hora de crear un comentario**

```
<QuerySet [<Post: 18/05/2022 prueba>, <Post: 18/05/2022 postprueba2>]>
[18/May/2022 22:24:20] "POST /posts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2885
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `views.py` no estás asignando el post al comentario.

```
comment = Comment(
    post=post.pk, # <-- Te faltaría esto.
    content=request.POST["comment"],
    author_id=request.user.pk
)
```